# Referencing elements in n-dimensional Numpy arays, when the dimensionality is variable

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to be able to reference an element of a Numpy n-dimensional array when the shape of the array itself is variable.

For a 4-D array, I know I'd be able to access some specific element index (let's say the very first one for argument) by direct referencing, for example

```
array[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

But what if the next iteration I only had a 3-dimension array? I'd need;

```
array[1, 1, 1]
```

And then a 6-dimension array? Then I'd need

```
array[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Assuming that I know the appropriate index for each case, how do I go about programatically referencing array indices when the shape can change?

Thanks

Comment: `a.ravel()[0]`?

Comment: Your question sounds to me like "Assuming that I know the appropriate index for each case, how do I index for each case?". What am I missing in your question?

Comment: For a given subroutine, if I knew that the array would be 2D, 3D or 4D etc it'd be easy. If - however - the dimensionality of the array was itself variable, even if I knew that I needed to access index [1,1,1,1], how would I do so in a way that I could then access index [1,1] in the next iteration? I'm looking for something like  array(index) where index is a variable length list, which I've so far been unable to find. Shortorian may have a workaround below - will check it out

Comment: The index can be a tuple.  `idx =(1,)*arr.ndim` and `arr[idx]`.  Obviously you can be fancier,starting with  a list or array, throw in `slice` objects,ettc.

Comment: hpaulj - that's the answer thanks. If you wanted to post an 'answer' I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

you can always reshape the array and expand the index:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10*100*77*10*10).reshape(10,100,77,10,10)
print(a[1,2,5,9,9])
#output: 785999

def new_index(index, array):
    shape = array.shape
    terms = [v*np.prod(shape[i+1:]) for i,v in enumerate(index)]
    return int(sum(terms))

# make a 1-D array
oneD = a.reshape(np.prod(a.shape))
print(oneD[new_index([1,2,5,9,9], a)])
#output: 785999
```

I'm assuming there's a numpy function that does this but I don't know it off the top of my head

Comment: Thanks shortorian - this achieves what I wanted, but like you, I'd be suprised if there wasn't a Numpy function to do the same. Will mark as solution if no one provides something more elegant. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

hpaulj had the answer I was after. I'd tried referencing via a list (created by appending values with increasing dimension), but not via a tuple.

With the variable dimension index to be accessed as a list, first convert to a tuple, and then reference;

```
list_index = [1,1,1,1]
tuple_index = tuple(list_index)
result = array[tuple_index]
```